# What do the find() and sort()mean in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongoose, so there are something I don't quite understand.

The code like the below:

The question is

1 I can't find have two parameters [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)(it is like find({})), why in this code find have two parameters?

2what does "sort(order+sort)" mean ? I am confused.

```
    var sort = req.query.sort || "created";
    var order = (req.query.order === "asc" ? "-" : "");
    var limit = req.query.limit || "20";
    var offset = req.query.offset || "0";

    Opportunities.find(filterObject, '-email')
            .sort(order + sort)
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .populate('tags')
            .populate('location')
            .exec(function (err, opportunities) {
                if (err) return handleError(res, err);
                return res.json(200, opportunities);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [second argument to `find`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) is the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)) of result objects. That is, it is a list of fields you want to include or exclude in each result object found by the query. [If you use field names prefaced by minus signs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) (`-foo`), then you are signifying that you want all fields *except* that listed fields. So, the argument `-email` means, "When showing me results, exclude the `email` field, but include all other fields".

[The `sort` function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) can also use field names with or without a minus sign, indicating whether the results should be sorted descending or ascending:

> The sort order of each path is ascending unless the path name is prefixed with `-` which will be treated as descending.

The `order` variable is either the one-character string `-` or the empty string, based on the desired direction of the sort. This gets prepended to the field name used to sort the results (i.e., the `sort` variable).

Comment: One more question, if I want to exclude more than one field, can I still you minus signs, just like " find(filterObject, '-email, phone') "?  Thanks

Comment: @fhlkm See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select, which gives the example `'-c -d'` to exclude `c` and `d`. (Separate your names by space only, and use a minus before each one.)